# Model this context with 2 or 3 tables?

Tags: database, database-design

I have some doubts if are needed 3 or just 2 tables for the following context:

- In a conference management system, all users in the system can create new conferences.
- The user that creates a conference is the conference creator of that conference
- The conference creator has a field that the not exists in the user's table that is the "description". Also the conference creator when creates a new conference he needs to fill a form where he has to introduce the name and email of the conference creator, these two fields are automatically populated with the name and email of the authenticated user. But the conference creator can overwrite these fields, but overwrite these fields in the context of that conference that he is creating not overwrite his name and email in the context of his user account.

So I don't know if I should have only two tables with a one to many relationships (1 user can create multiple conferences), and store the conference creator description, conference creator email, and conference creator name in the conference table (but sometimes the name and/or email in the conference table will be the same of the name and/or email of the user´s table):

```
User: idUser, name, email, password
Conference: idConference, name, description, date, ..., conferenceCreatorDescription, conferenceCreatorEmail, conferenceCreatorName
```

Or a 1 to 1 relationship between User and ConferenceCreator and one to many between ConferenceCreator and Conference:

```
User: idUser, name, email, password
ConferenceCreator: idConferenceCreator, name, description, email, idUser (fk)
Conference: idConference, name, description, date, ..., idUser(fk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use your two-table approach and store the User information in the Conference record.  Bear in mind that the User data in the Conference record is a "snapshot" of the User at the time he created the conference, so it's reasonable to store it in a time-stamped format.

This is similar to why you store item details in an invoice-detail record - if the price on item 1234 changes on January 10th 2018, you can't change the price retroactively on every item 1234 that you sold before then.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, but can you give an example of how the value of the column is stored in a time-stamped format? And it's not equal store the conference creator name, conference creator email and conference creator description in the conference table and store also a timestamp when the conference is created?

Comment: @JohnZ, by "time-stamped" I just meant you would store the values that were in the User record at the time the User created the Conference - you'll have to decide which fields you need to keep.  However, I would certainly expect a "Created Datetime" field on the Conference record.  Does that help make it clear?